# Mongodb aggregate $match a document OR all

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an parameterized mongodb aggregate query where the parameter receives a given ObjectID to be filtered or NULL if I want to return all documents. I mean, I would like to use the same pipeline to return one OR all documents.

My pipeline query is:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {'$match': { _id : <MYUSERPARAM> } }
]);
```

The value of **MYUSERPARAM** will have a given ObjectId to be filtered or have some value if I don't want to filter a single document and I want to return all the documents.

Then my system will replace the **MYUSERPARAM** and run the query, such as:

To filter a single document:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {'$match': { _id : ObjectId("5e2b9ab8b1dbae5124e4b635") } }
]);
```

or
somehow return all documents:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {'$match': { _id : $all } }
]);
```

But the approach above is not working.

How can I have a pipeline query to filter a single document OR return all the documents just changing a single value/parameter in the query like the example above ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like NoSQL injection:

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {'$match': { _id : {$ne: ""} } }
]);

or

db.user.aggregate([
  {'$match': { _id : {$exists: true} } }
]);
```